# What is the max Gold and Guild Seals?

Tags: fable-3

I was just running around killing Sand Furies and I wondered, what is the max amount of gold you can have in the Treasury as well on your person? Same with Guild Seals, what is the max, seeming I have ~600

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The max amount of gold: 5 million.

The max amount of Guild Seals: well since the total *required* for unlocking everything is 1512 (according to the wiki), I would say around that number.

Comment: Are you sure on the gold, because I have ~7 Million gold that I carry around

Comment: that's in the vault, on your person there is not really any fixed limit, just when they run out of digits... 9,999,999 most likely. No really purpose to have that much gold though.

Comment: I get 110,000 Gold every 5 minutes, I kinda bought ALL of Albion.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I just got the max amount of gold if anyone is still curious. While transferring money between two of my profiles on local multiplayer the transfer digits were doing that glitch where it takes forever to get to 100 000. Then I quickly let go and pressed the left thumbstick to the right very fast. And boom the digits went over 1 billion. Upon accepting the"gift" on my other profile I was handed a cool 999,999,999 :D[image]